# Forced shutdown destroyed network ability

Tags: network-manager, suspend, internet, shutdown

Hi I come to you for help as I did something kind of stupid on a pc that's very important to me and that I would like not to have to format completely.

Yesterday, as I was about to shutdown everything and go to bed, I was watching a YouTube video with my headset on. When I go to shutdown, my finger slips and I accidentally press the "suspend" button instead. In the Suspension procedure my headset gets disconnected and my YouTube video started blasting from the speakers on a loop, this creates the kind of panic needed to make a stupid decision.

In order to stop the noise, since it was kind of late, I forced shutdown the pc, by keeping the On/Off button pressed for 7 seconds. I underline that I forced the shutdown while the pc was already in the process of suspending itself.

Today I opened the pc and everything works fine except for the fact that all network capabilities of my pc are gone.

My pc connects to every network, the widget says it's connected, it connects, disconnects and reconnects on command. But actually there is no network capability, it can't browse the web, thunderbird can't reach IMAP servers, ssh can't connect to anything, openVPN can't connect to the already set up VPN profile I have and when you call apt-get install the pc can't connect to the Ubuntu archive to download packages.

This is to say that clearly there is no actual internet connection but my pc does not seem to notice that and keeps saying connected. I add that this happens with every connection possible both cable and WiFi. The pc can't even access pages inside the network, like the router configuration page for example.

Is there anyway to hard reset the whole network module? I already tried all of the commands to restart network manager with systemctl that I found on different questions on similar topics. The command runs, but still no result.

Please help me, it would take a ton of time and effort to save all the work I have in this laptop and that is now rendered impossible to back up on the cloud.

**EDIT:** I am running Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish on an acer-travelMate laptop

I tried power cycling, didn't work.

Comment: Silly question but have you tried another power cycle? Shutdown, count to 10, boot. If you already have, or if this doesn't work, could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the brand/model of the computer (2) any log information that might point to a network issue. With this, it may be possible to offer more specific next steps 

Comment: Hi yes, I tried another power cycle, nothing changed. I added the edit as you suggested but honestly for what concerns the logs I really never found any log pointing to a specific network issue

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a somewhat similar problem.
Basically, my Ubuntu shut down with a certain VPN address and wanted to reconnect with another address.  However, my ISP was trying to reconnect with the prior address.  You may be able to reset the router and make it receptive to a new 'handshake'.  I can't address what might reset the computer/vpn, there's not enough info there nor could I address it in any case.

Comment: forgot to update the question, the issue actually solved itself after a few days with no particular action on my end, it is still a mistery to this date for me.